# How to display Text on MSBuild only when ItemGroup Count > 0?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildextensionpack, msbuild-itemgroup

I have following Target:

```
<Target Name="RemoveUnusedCopiedfiles" AfterTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">

    <ItemGroup>
        <FileToDelete Include="@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory -> '$(TargetDir)\%(FileName)%(Extension)')" Condition="%(Extension) == '.pdb' OR %(Extension) == '.xml'"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(FileToDelete)"/>
    <Message Text="Deleted Files @(FileToDelete -> '%(FullPath)', ', ')"
             Importance="high"/>  // Problem Here I need only show Deleted Files if FileToDelete.Count > 0

    <!-- Remove other unused files -->
    <Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).nuspec"/>
</Target>
```

I don't know exactly how to make above `<Message>` only appeard if FileToDelete variable `Count > 0`? How to do that in MSBuild?

I always get this line: [Image are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87mlx.png)

Is there something in MSBuild collection value:  i.e:  `Condition = "@(FileToDelete.Count > 0)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like this:

```
<Message Text="Deleted Files @(FileToDelete -> '%(FullPath)', ', ')"
         Importance="high" Condition="'@(FileToDelete)' != ''"/>
```

The `@(...)`, in a "string context", will expand to the items, delimited by a semicolon. Or an empty string, if the `ItemGroup` is empty.